# My new app has only main activity and its acivity_main layout but it crashes when run on mobile

Tags: android

Dears,

I am starting a new app and it has a main activity ( even without a detailed code) and it layout xml file , and when i try to run it on my mobile it crashes immediately, could you please help ?

i tried and did check almost every other file like manifest and ....

it is more or less like the hellop world code but i do not know why it is does not work and crashes on start

Here is the *MainActivity* java and the layout codes

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

`activity_main.xml`:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
            android:text="Settings"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="2dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingTop="4dp"
                android:paddingRight="8dp"
                android:paddingBottom="4dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_globe_primary_24dp" />

            <Switch
                android:id="@+id/enable_switch"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:text="Enable Geofences"
                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:onClick="onAddPlaceButtonClicked"
            android:text="Add New Location"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Button"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
            android:text="Location List"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="2dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/places_list_recycler_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:padding="4dp"
            android:src="@drawable/powered_by_google_light" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:autoLink="web"
            android:paddingBottom="4dp"
            android:text="http://www.google.com/policies/privacy"
            android:textAlignment="center" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Stacktrace please.

Comment: Also, post your entire MainActivity class.